# RollupJS `resolve failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime'`

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, rollupjs

## rollup-error-example

Illustrate a (possible) problem with rollup.

Am I missing something? Here is a project with a minimal configuration to
reproduce the "problem" I running into. The problem seems only to be extraneous
command-line logging without affecting the bundle itself; i.e. the bundle is
created correctly and accurately.

This project displays the output:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup.js
node_modules/nan
resolve failed:  { Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.requireRelative.resolve (/Users/jkalis/Pro/QL/WebCore/luxui/rollup-testing/node_modules/require-relative/index.js:30:17)
    at resolve (/Users/jkalis/Pro/QL/WebCore/luxui/rollup-testing/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:25:26)
    at findAndRemove (/Users/jkalis/Pro/QL/WebCore/luxui/rollup-testing/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:67:11)
    at /Users/jkalis/Pro/QL/WebCore/luxui/rollup-testing/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:111:13
    at Array.map (native)
    at loadPreset (/Users/jkalis/Pro/QL/WebCore/luxui/rollup-testing/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/lib/serialize.js:103:29)
    at module.exports (/Users/jkalis/Pro/QL/WebCore/luxui/rollup-testing/node_modules/modify-babel-preset/index.js:97:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jkalis/Pro/QL/WebCore/luxui/rollup-testing/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } babel-runtime
```

The command(s) to reproduce this are:

- `npm run bundle`, or
- `./node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup.js`

In other projects I have similar issues with additional resolve "failures" that
seem not to affect the bundle itself. Is this something that is easily fixable?

I have created a Git repository - https://github.com/kalisjoshua/rollup-error-example - which exhibits this behavior.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you try to install the most recent version of `babel-preset-es2015-rollup`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The repo on github that shows how to reproduce the error shows version 1.2.0 of babel-preset-es2015-rollup being used. I found the following on github:

- https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1141
- https://github.com/rollup/babel-preset-es2015-rollup/issues/18

It looks like the babel-preset-es2015-rollup package just needs updated to latest, as after I tried that, the error no longer occured.

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index b1f4325..d5251fd 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@
   "license": "MIT",
   "dependencies": {
     "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
-    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^1.2.0",
+    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^3.0.0",
     "rollup": "^0.36.4",
     "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.6.1"
   }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I could not figure this out for the life of me.